# Problema con link de activacion enviado atraves de email!

Tags: reactjs, email, nodemailer, 404

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto y sucede que envio atraves de gmail un email al usuario que intenta registrarse, pero cuando clickeo ese mail para activar la cuenta me devuelve un 404 con http://localhost:3000/activation/"codigodeltoken"

```
router.post("/create-user", upload.single("file"), async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const { name, email, password, avatar } = req.body;
        const userEmail = await User.findOne({ email })
        if (userEmail) {
            const filename = req.file.filename;
            const filePath = `uploads/${filename}`;
            fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.status(500).json({ message: "Se produjo un error al eliminar el archivo" })
                } else {
                    res.json({ message: "Se eliminó el archivo satisfactoriamente" })
                }
            })
            return next(new ErrorHandler("El usuario ya existe", 400))
        }

        const filename = req.file.filename;
        const fileUrl = path.join(filename);

        const user = {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            password: password,
            avatar: fileUrl,
        }


        const activationToken = createActivationToken(user);

        const activationUrl = `http://localhost:3000/activation/${activationToken}`;

        try {
            await sendMail({
                email: user.email,
                subject: "Activar cuenta",
                message: `Hola ${user.name}, por favor haz click en el link para activar tu cuenta: ${activationUrl}`
            })
            res.status(201).json({
                success: true,
                message: `Revisa tu email:- ${user.email} para activar tu cuenta!`
            })
        } catch (error) {
            return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500));
        }

    } catch (error) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 400))
    }
});

//create activation token
const createActivationToken = (user) => {
    return jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACTIVATION_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: "10m",
    });
};
```

No logro ver en que estoy fallando. Es un tutorial que se encuentra en youtube. El utiliza create-react app, mientras que yo estoy utilizando Vite. Sera eso?

Comment: en `http://localhost:3000/` debe existir un servidor que tome la solicitud ( `localhost` resuelve a la misma computadora desde donde le haces click/accedes ; localhost no siempre es igual a `::1` / `127.0.0.1` ) dicho servidor debe tener una forma de procesar lo que llega en `/activation/` ( tal vez te falte definir un `router.get('activation')` en la app )